# How do I show that if a hypothesis implies not, it's the same as saying the proposition equals false (coq)?

Tags: functional-programming, coq, proof, coq-tactic

I want to prove two characters are not equal. My environment currently looks like this:

```
H: c1 = c2 -> not
_____________________
Goal: (c1 =? c2)%char = false
```

It won't allow me to apply H or rewrite H to solve the goal, and H is not invertible. The goal directly follows from the hypothesis, so how can I prove this? Do I need a helper lemma?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is a typo in your hypothesis `H`  ?
Do you mean `not (c1 = c2)` (or `c1 <> c2`, or `c1 = c2 -> False`) ?

If so, you may apply a lemma of Standard Library:

```
Search (_ =? _)%char. 

Goal forall c1 c2: ascii,
    c1 <> c2 -> (c1 =? c2)%char = false.
Proof.
  intros c1 c2; apply eqb_neq.
Qed.
```

It may be interesting to look at the proof of `eqb_neq`too, in order to understand how to prove this kind of lemmas.